# How to push value from async response data to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a client-server project. As I writing the script in HTML. I have a hard time push the data I have to array. Here is the source code snippets:

```
    var latitude = [];
    async function getapi(url){
        const response = await fetch(url);
        var data = await response.json();
        show(data);
        return data;
    }
    
    getapi(api_url);
    function show(data){
        for (r in data){
            latitude.push(data[r]['DepLat'];
            var dep_marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({color: 'red'})
            .setLngLat([data[r]['DepLng'],data[r]['DepLat']])
            .addTo(map);
            var arr_marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({color: 'cyan'})
            .setLngLat([data[r]['ArrLng'],data[r]['ArrLat']])
            .addTo(map);
        }
    }
```

The result I have in `latitude` after calling show(data) is still empty. Thank you.

Comment: Please, try to explain better your problem.

Comment: what does `data` look like?

Comment: Did you wait for the function to actually execute? Tip: `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. The line where you push the value is missing the closing parentheses.

```
function show(data){
    for (r in data){
    // your code says .push(
         latitude.push(data[r]['DepLat'];
      // rest of your code
 }
```

Do it this way

```
function show(data){
    for (r in data){
        latitude.push(data[r]['DepLat']);
       // rest of your code
}
```